# Why i have invalid css at sass?

Tags: reactjs, sass, node-sass

So i have this sass file:

```
.Row
    display: flex
    .Field
        width: 100%
        margin-right: 16px
        margin-bottom: 16px
```

When i want to add for nested .Field property min-width: 180px i'm getting this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/styles/main.sass (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/styles/main.sass)
    .Field
              ^
      Invalid CSS after "    .Field {} }": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"
      in /Users/isee/Work/Web/Projects/cardbox/src/styles/main.sass (line 61, column 16)
```

Why? If im trying to add new lines with:

```
.Row
    .Field
        min-width: 180px
```

after code above everything ok.

**Node-sass 4.12.0, using with react 16.8.4**

[image]

Comment: Can you share exactly how it looks when you get the error at compiling? since I tried and everything seems fine with your attempt.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Invalid CSS after "    .Field {} }": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"
```

So first you need to add { }

```
.Row {
    display: flex
    .Field {
        width: 100%
        margin-right: 16px
        margin-bottom: 16px } 
}
```

Comment: No, Sass can work without braces. Something else must be going on. See also my attempt to reproduce the OP's problem [on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gVgzrY).

Comment: Sass can work withour curly braces and without semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add {} and also ';' , something like below

```
.Row{
display: flex;
.Field{
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;}}
```

Comment: Sass can work withour curly braces and without semicolon.